# If there are 3 noncollinear points on a plane, is a vector of 2 of those points a linearly independent vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say there are 3 points: P, Q, R

and I know they are noncollinear points in a plane. Would the vectors Q - P and R - P be linearly independent vectors?

This is my first question on here, please let me know if I missed anything or if I am doing something wrong! Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Sorry, would Q-P be linearly independent from say... R-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. A set of **two** nonzero vectors $\{u,v\}$ is linearly independent if and only if they are not parallel. The only way your vectors can be parallel is if all three lie on the same line.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up!

Answer (score 0):

Hont: Recall that $\{v\}$ is linear independent iff $v\neq0$.